# R academictwitteR - download tweets which contain at least one word of each vector

Tags: r, twitter

for my research question I am looking at tweets which contain words from topic1 **and** topic2. If I am just looking for one topic at a time it is pretty straight forward.

```
vec_topic1 <- c("word_1","word_2","word_3")
vec_topic2 <- c("word_a","word_b","word_c")

tweets_topic1 <-  get_all_tweets(query = vec_topic1,
                                 start_tweets = "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                 end_tweets = "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                                 file = "tweets_topic1",
                                 data_path = "data/",
                                 n = 500,
                                 )

tweets_topic2 <-  get_all_tweets(query = vec_topic2,
                                 start_tweets = "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                 end_tweets = "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                                 file = "tweets_topic2",
                                 data_path = "data/",
                                 n = 500,
                                 )
```

This works just fine. Each word contained in the vector gets connected with an <kbd>OR</kbd>. The console output states:

```
query: (word_1 OR word_2 OR word_3)
```

Basically, what I want to do now is to connect these two vectors with an <kbd>AND</kbd>. So I want the output to contain at least one word from <kbd>vec_topic1</kbd> and at least one word from <kbd>vec_topic2</kbd>.

I tried the following:

```
tweets_both_topics <- get_all_tweets(query = c(vec_topic1, "AND", vec_topic2),
                                     start_tweets = "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                     end_tweets = "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                                     file = "tweets_both_topics",
                                     data_path = "data/",
                                     n = 500,
                                     )
```

The console output for the query looks promising.

```
query: (word_1 OR word_2 OR word_3 AND word_a OR word_b OR word_c)
```

I do get a dataset with words of both vectors, but there is never more than one word of both vectors per tweet. So, it seems to ignore the <kbd>AND</kbd> or at least not understand that I am trying to look for at least one word from each vector per tweet.

I hope I was able to explain my problem. Does anybody have advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is not an elegant solution, the following has worked for me:

```
tweets_both_topics <- get_all_tweets(query = "(word_1,word_2,word_3)
                                              (word_a,word_b,word_c)",        
                                     start_tweets = "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                     end_tweets = "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                                     file = "tweets_both_topics",
                                     data_path = "data/",
                                     n = 500,
                                     )
```

This way I get tweets containing one word of each vector.